# Setting Up Keycloak for High Availability with Active/Active Load Balancing

Tags: java, authentication, authorization, keycloak, load-balancing

I plan to integrate Keycloak into a Java application developed with Spring Boot and Project Reactor. The application will be deployed across two or three servers, and traffic will be managed by two active load balancers. Should I host all Keycloak instances on the same server as their respective application instances, or should I separate the Keycloak instances onto dedicated servers and then manage traffic after Keycloak using an additional load balancer?

I carefully reviewed the official documentation but was unable to find the information I needed.